# Add one to integer displayed in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` and when the user presses a button, I want the label to add one to its value. But I'm having a bit of trouble with this. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addButton2:(id)sender {
    int integer = 1;
    integer++;
    [label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",integer]];
}
```

Comment: you edited your question, could you make it clear what you changed. the previous version would crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int doesn't respond to stringValue ...

the original question had [int stringValue] which wont work

```
-(IBAction)addButton2:(id)sender {
    static int myInt = 1;
    myInt++;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
    [label setText:string];  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add static to your int, then the integer only will be initialized once.

```
- (IBAction)addButton2:(id)sender 
{
    static int integer = 1;
    integer++;
    [label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", integer]];
}
```

Comment: @Man of One Way hey when i do this, i have to press the button twice before it actually starts to count. Do u know why its doing this??

Comment: first the value is nothing, then its 1 and then 1 again?

Comment: ok i got it i wasn't setting the integer to 1 :D haha thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting `integer` to 1 every time the Button is pressed, then increase it by one.
This will always result into `2` being displayed on the label.
You will need to move the initialization outside of this function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    integer = 1;
    [label1 setText:[integer stringValue]];
}

- (IBAction)addButton2:(id)sender
{
    integer++;
    [label1 setText:[integer stringValue]];  
}
```

Comment: in the C world you would always just make the auto a static